# sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0

Tags: python, python-sphinx

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\item\code_serv\documents\api>make html
>   Running Sphinx v1.6.2 loading pickled environment... failed:
>
> Can't get attribute 'WarningStream' on `<module 'sphinx.util.nodes' from 'c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx\\util\\nodes.py'>`

Theme error:

> sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since `version 1.4.0`.
>   Please install it manually.(`pip install sphinx_rtd_theme`)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I found another issue, I had two installations of sphinx, one via `pip` and another one via `brew`. Deleting one (I chose to remove installation done via `brew` ) solved this issue.

```
brew remove sphinx-doc
```

If it still doesnt work, try uninstalling and reinstalling

```
pip3  uninstall sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme
pip3  install sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme
```

Comment: this is a good solution that works for brew based installations, install python via brew - then sphinx and sphinx_rtd_theme through pip3. Helped on a Hetzner Managed Server

Answer (score 0):

In my case (building from [RTD theme source](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_theme_path)), the problem seemed to be caused by a change in behaviour of the `html_theme_path` config value in `conf.py`. Whilst paths relative to the makefile directory used to be accepted, paths must now be relative to the configuration directory:

> **html_theme_path**
>
> A list of paths that contain custom themes, either as subdirectories or as zip files. Relative paths are taken as relative to the configuration directory.
>
> New in version 0.6.
>
> — [Sphinx documentation > Configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_theme_path)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Windows 10 Pro laptop. I had installed Python 3.9 from the Windows store. I had to first find where Python and pip applications were installed and add that to the PATH variable. This was in a folder that was looked:

```
c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Scripts
```

Then I installed sphinx using:

```
pip install -U sphinx
```

Then I had to set the SPHINXBUILD env variable to the right value:

```
SPHINXBUILD="c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe"
```

When I tried to use the sphinx_rtd_theme I kept getting the error:

```
Theme error:
sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0. Please install it 
manually.(pip install sphinx_rtd_theme)
```

I ran the following command:

```
pip install sphinx_rtd_theme
```

But when I tried to run `make html` it gave the error:

```
Running Sphinx v3.5.1

Configuration error:
There is a syntax error in your configuration file: bad input (conf.py, line 57)
```

Finally I had to make the following changes in my conf.py file:

```
# Add this to the top of the conf.py file
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\ <username>\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages'))
import sphinx_rtd_theme

extensions = [
   "sphinx_rtd_theme",
]
```

It looks like sphinx-build is not able to get the location of the sphinx_rtd_theme package unless you give the explicit path in the manner above. “¯_(ツ)_/¯“