# sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0. even if the theme is installed

Tags: python, python-sphinx

## The issue

running `make html` on Sphinx and using `sphinx-rtd-theme` work no more

## A hint

The preview works on Visual Studio Code (vscode) using exactly the same conda environment.

## The error on the terminal

> make html

```
Running Sphinx v3.3.1

Theme error:
sphinx_rtd_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0. 
Please install it manually.(pip install sphinx_rtd_theme)
make: *** [Makefile:20: html] Error 2
```

## Python version

> python --version

```
Python 3.9.0
```

## Installed Python libraries

```
pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------------------
alabaster                     0.7.12
Babel                         2.9.0
certifi                       2020.11.8
chardet                       3.0.4
doc8                          0.8.1
docutils                      0.16
idna                          2.10
imagesize                     1.2.0
Jinja2                        2.11.2
livereload                    2.6.3
MarkupSafe                    1.1.1
mccabe                        0.6.1
packaging                     20.7
pbr                           5.5.1
pip                           20.2.4
pycodestyle                   2.6.0
pydocstyle                    5.1.1
pyflakes                      2.2.0
Pygments                      2.7.2
pylama                        7.7.1
pyparsing                     2.4.7
pytz                          2020.4
requests                      2.25.0
restructuredtext-lint         1.3.2
rstcheck                      3.3.1
setuptools                    49.6.0.post20201009
six                           1.15.0
snowballstemmer               2.0.0
Sphinx                        3.3.1
sphinx-autobuild              2020.9.1
sphinx-rtd-theme              0.5.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4
stevedore                     3.2.2
tornado                       6.1
Unidecode                     1.1.1
urllib3                       1.26.2
wheel                         0.35.1
```

## config.py file

```py
# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
import datetime

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'Project name'
copyright = '2020, ALT-F1 SPRL'
author = 'Me, MySelf and I'

# The short X.Y version
version = u'v' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = version + ' ' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H.%M')

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

extensions = [
    'sphinx_rtd_theme',
]

templates_path = ['_templates']

exclude_patterns = []

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']

todo_include_todos = True

# CSS customization

def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('css/custom.css')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sphinx\_rtd\_theme is no longer a hard dependency since version 1.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940890/sphinx-rtd-theme-is-no-longer-a-hard-dependency-since-version-1-4-0)

Comment: Is this issue specific to Conda? Or do the solutions in the other threads solve it? Normally installing `sphinx-rtd-theme` with pip to your environment solves the problem.

Comment: @bad_coder the answers you are referring to do not help. sphinx-rtd-theme is installed, the issues comes from somewhere else.

Comment: In my opinion you should edit the question and add any tags that may be specific to your environment like [tag:conda], [tag:read-the-docs], etc...To give the question more specific visibility.

Comment: @Abdelkrim what do you mean "preview works on Visual Studio Code"? Most previews of reStructuredText do not run through Sphinx. Next, error messages rarely lie. Try `pip uninstall sphinx-rtd-theme` then `pip install sphinx-rtd-theme`. If that doesn't work, your virtual environment might be messed up. Delete it, recreate it, and reinstall packages.

Comment: @steve-piercy, I uninstalled and installed sphinx-rtd-theme but the error remains.
I created a new environment using python 3.8 and now it works. ?!?
thanks dude

Comment: A virtual environment can get screwed up in many ways. ;)